# Setting mTLS connection to Kafka in Spring with a dynamically loaded certificate

Tags: spring, ssl, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am working on a Spring Kafka project that uses the following library `org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:3.0.12` to connect to a Kafka server. It dynamically loads a certificate with key from an Azure KeyVault and needs to use it to establish mTLS connection with Kafka.

One way to do it is by setting the properties `ssl.keystore.location` and `ssl.truststore.location`, but these properties require paths to filesystem stored keystore which I don't have.

Another approach is to use the property `ssl.engine.factory.class` by providing path to a class which creates `SSLContext` and `SSLEnginge`. The problem with this approach is that it doesn't have access to Spring context beans, since an instance of this class is created by Kafka library. I need to use the beans to get a certificate with key.

Is there any alternative solution that would fulfill the requirements?